# Chrome box-shadow bugs

Tags: google-chrome

Faced with a bug in google chrome 45.0.2454.46 beta (64-bit) and mac os 10.11, the shadow becomes cubes. Any idea how to fix? If you reduce the size of the shadow, the bug disappears.

Chrome - 
[image: Chrome bug]
Firefox -
[image: Firefox normal]

```css
.list-shadow__box {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.list-shadow__images {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 250px;
}    
.list-shadow__images:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .4s;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow .4s;
    -o-transition: box-shadow .4s;
    transition: box-shadow .4s;
}
.list-shadow__box .list-shadow__images:before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 200px 100px #616060;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-shadow__box">
    <div class="list-shadow__images"></div>
</div>
```

demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGVoYe

Answer (score 1):

Remove `overflow:hidden` in `.list-shadow__images`... your *shadow* is bigger than the div size...
That's why its look like a square.

```css
.list-shadow__box {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.list-shadow__images {
    position: relative;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    height: 250px;
}    
.list-shadow__images:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .4s;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow .4s;
    -o-transition: box-shadow .4s;
    transition: box-shadow .4s;
}
.list-shadow__box .list-shadow__images:before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 200px 100px #616060;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-shadow__box">
    <div class="list-shadow__images"></div>
</div>
```

Modified demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbLNEv

Comment: No?.. you say *"If you reduce the size of the shadow, the bug disappears"* and I say *"your shadow is bigger than the div size..."*... And If you have `overflow:hidden`... Look pretty clear to me. Sorry then, If this is *"not related"*, then clearly I didn't understand your problem.

Comment: Could you please try in a ***Stable Version of Chrome***? As a *beta* user, you should know that coding in *beta version* could give you more troubles than only this one. (And if it's a *beta* related and specific problem, you should do a ***bug report***, but in the *Project Page*, not here)